# Port is still closed after ufw

Tags: debian, iptables, ufw

On debian, I ran ufw allow 27015 on root and ufw status showed that it was allowed. However, on a port checker tool online, it said it was closed. During this test, a server was binded to that port, yet no connection could be established to it ingame.

Thanks

Comment: You need to have a program running using that port for it shown as open.

Comment: Did you verify that a process was listening on the port (`ss -lt`, if this is tcp 27015) ?  Does this machine have a publicly routable IP address, or does it have an RFC 1918 address behind a NAT device?

Comment: @Vlastimil As I said in the post, a running server was binded to that port.

Comment: @user4556274 For an odd reason it is listening for it on iPv6 (::ffff:127.0.0.1:27015) I want it to be like the other one, (iPv4: *:25565). They both run the same program but I'm trying to create the new on 27015

Comment: @Max604, that should accept connections via IPv4, but it is listening on the `lo` interface only.  If you want it to listen on a public interface, you need to adjust the configuration of the server you are running; that is not a firewall issue.

Comment: @user4556274 You should make that an answer.

Answer (score 3):

In comments it was noted that the server in question was listening on the `localhost` interface, not a public interface (`::ffff:127.0.0.1:27015`).

This would be an issue of configuring the particular software to listen on a public interface; not of firewall configuration.

Comment: The software is exactly the same for 25565 and 27015, the only difference is the port to bind to. The issue lies in the firewall configuration. It should show *:27015 but I do not know how to.

Comment: @Max604, the firewall will not change how your software attempts to bind a listening socket.  If you are using common software (_e.g._ `apache`) and post snippets of the configuration, someone may be able to help.  If you are using some more obscure game software, you will need to check the manuals and configuration yourself.  Even if the _port_ line is identical except for the port number, there may be configuration elsewhere instructing your software not to use your ethernet interfaces.

Comment: (continuing previous comment): For example, `sshd` uses two separate configuration items for this: you can specify the listening port on one line of `sshd_config`, and you specify the listening _address_ on a different line.  Good hygiene would keep these lines adjacent, but there is nothing in the configuration requiring that.

Comment: So what would you be your suggestion, this is trying to run a spigot server for minecraft.